# Put data back in socket buffer

Tags: windows, sockets, winsock2

Short question, didn't seem to find anything useful here or on Google: in the Winsock2 API, is it possible to put data back in the sockets internal buffer when you have retrieved it using `recv()` for example, so that is seems it was never actually read from the buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to inject data back into the socket's internal buffer.  Either use the `MSG_PEEK` flag to read data without removing it from the socket's buffer, or else read the socket data into your own buffer, and then do whatever you want with your buffer.  You could have your reading I/O logic always look for data in your buffer first, and then read more data from the socket only when your buffer does not have enough data to satisfy the read operation. Any data you inject back into your buffer will be seen by subsequent read operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MSG_PEEK flag in your recv() call

Comment: That is interesting indeed, but it is not what I actually asked. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It is not exactly what you asked but it seems to give you the functionality you need. Is it mandatory that you remove the data from the buffer and then put it back in it instead of just copying it from the buffer?

Comment: No, don't get me wrong. I can use this for sure, but it is not the answer to the question and therefor I can't accept it (for further reader where this might be indeed mandatory).

Comment: I really couldn't care less if you accept it or not, I just don't understand what you really want to know. Are you saying: I need a solution in case I accidentally removed the data from the buffer without meaning to? Because I can't really see any scenario that would require a rewrite of the data to the buffer after it is removed. If you need to only read specific data, peek first, read if  later if you need to.

Comment: @Jori There is no *other* answer to your question, ergo this is the answer.